# Pin compatibility between STM32L4X1 and STM32F1

Tags: stm32

Does STM32L4X1C series have a pin compatibility with STM32F103xx, 107xx or 207xx?

How can I find the other STMs that be pin compatible with the series I want?

Comment: Not exactly, no.  But many of the pinouts are similar enough that you can design a board to support two different classes of chip in the same package by carefully accomodating the differences in supply pins, etc.  **You will have to compare the data sheets yourself** as purchase and part search questions are not on topic here.

Comment: Typically, pin-compatible products are listed in the datasheet somewhere, under "compatible products", "upgrade paths", "design migration" or something along the lines.

Answer (score 2):

**[STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html)** (free registration required to download) can help you find MCUs that are pin-compatible with a particular MCU and pinout.

Start a project, select a MCU, configure the pins you intend to use, and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for a listing. You may probably want to uncheck the *Ingore...* options there, and repeat the search.